# Chrome Debugger for JS file only

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So. Dumb question.

I am using developer tools on chrome as essentially my IDE in the source tab. I have a JS file writing a program with no associated html/css files. Is there anyway for me to utilize the debugger for my JS file? Specifically I want to step into a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In developer mode, select Sources tab, then navigate to your JS files in the left side. In the right panel, you can add a breakpoint to any line by pressing the line number which has a real js statement. Then you can run your application again to debug your js scripts.

The picture below is an example(Line 33 of assert.js is selected).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to debug/test your JS code, Chrome is only one of them.

1. QUOKKA

Quokka.js is a developer productivity tool for rapid JavaScript / TypeScript prototyping. Runtime values are updated and displayed in your IDE next to your code, as you type.

[image]

2. Runkit notebook
   RunKit notebooks completely remove the friction of trying new ideas. With one click you’ll have a sandboxed JavaScript environment where you can instantly switch node versions, use every npm module without having to wait to install it, and even visualize your results. No more configuration, just straight to coding.
   [image]
3. Hopa
   Hopa is a zero config JavaScript/TypeScript runner right in your terminal.
4. JSComplete playground
   This is a playground for JavaScript and React. You can use it to test simple code or prototype ideas. It requires a modern browser that understands ES2015 (ES6).
   [image]
5. VSCode extensions Javascript REPL
   Javascript REPL is a javascript playground for Visual Studio Code with live feedback(logs or errors) as you type, besides your code, in a log explorer, or in an output channel. It supports Javascript, TypeScript, CoffeeScript and it can be used for development in Node.js projects or with front-end frameworks like React, Vue, Angular, Svelte etc.

[image]